# issue with keyword search on google play

Tags: android, google-play

I submitted an android app in google play a few months ago, and from some reason, even though my company name is mentioned everywhere in the description and title, when searching it on the google play search window, it never comes up.

am i missing something here? is there a place for keywords like in the apple app store, that i am missing? my promo text field is empty by the way, maybe thats the problem?

thanks.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: How do you reach google-play team? We have similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you email their developer program or post a question on their Google Group.

Comment: @moshikafya since you accepted this answer, I assumed you had sent an inquiry but did you ever get a reply?